# remove DD-WRT from DIR-615

Tags: dd-wrt, firmware

I have two dir-615 routers with dd-wrt, however I want to remove dd-wrt from one of them and reflash original firmware to this router. are there anything I need to do prior to this, or can I just upload the original firmware without anything special needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the dd-wrt website, be sure to perform a [30/30/30 hard reset](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30) before you do *anything* with the firmware.

To restore your original firmware, download it from the manufacturer's [website](http://www.dlink.com/products/default.aspx?pid=DIR-615&tab=3). You *should* be able to just upload the original firmware after the 30/30/30 reset, but I would search/ask the [dd-wrt forums](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/) to see if there are caveats for your particular router. Be careful, and good luck!

Comment: This [link](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/D-Link_DIR-615_rev_E3#How_to_restore_to_factory_firmware) shows you how to do it no need to do a 30/30/30 reset.

Answer (score 2):

This process works for hardware rev C1 for sure, and probably for others as well:

1. Download the latest firmware for the router from D-Link (e.g. [here](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/dir-615-wireless-n-300-router) for US models).
2. Set your PC's Ethernet adapter to use static IP address 192.168.0.2 and netmask 255.255.255.0. Connect your PC to a router LAN port.
3. Activate the router's bootloader by pressing and holding the reset button until the power light continually blinks amber. (It will blink just a few times after holding for a couple seconds, but needs about 30 seconds to get to the continual blink.)
4. Use **Firefox** to connect to 192.168.0.1 and upload the firmware. The router reboots itself when flashing is complete.

   Note that with **Internet Explorer**, **Chrome**, [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), and likely others, the bootloader ignores the uploaded firmware and **never responds** to the HTTP request. (Fortunately, while only very old versions Internet Explorer don't trigger the bug in the bootloader's HTTP stack, all version of Firefox, including the latest, are compatible. See the [OpenWrt DIR-615 caveat](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-615#browser.issues) for details.)
5. Set your PC's Ethernet adapter to use DHCP. After the router assigns it an IP address (so you know the router has finished booting), reset the router to factory default configuration by pressing and holding the reset button until the power light continually blinks amber again. Then power cycle the router.

Answer (score 1):

I've had installed DD-WRT on my DIR-615 rev. D1. Today I wanted go back to original D-Link firmware, but uploading failed with actual Firefox Quantum and ESR and Palemoon, no response, DD-WRT was still present. But uploading worked with K-Meleon 76.0, yeah! :-)
It's unbelievable, but it was a browser problem!

Comment: Yes, browser issues! Only internet explorer properly worked for me on that recovery UI.

Comment: This works for linux system `curl -v -i -F "firmware=@factory.bin" 192.168.0.1`