# How do I flash DIR-615 from the recovery console?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, flashing

I have installed dd-wrt on my DIR-615, but I now want to flash the stock firmware on it. However, while I can get into the recovery console (hold reset button and power on until power light flashes), I cannot upload the firmware. I am aware of the 100-continue as well as this question: [remove DD-WRT from DIR-615](https://superuser.com/questions/216009/remove-dd-wrt-from-dir-615), but I cannot manage to flash anything.

*In essence, the problem is that the client (browser, curl, etc) sends a "Expect: 100-continue" but since the router recovery console only supports HTML 1.0, it never replies with a 100-continue status.* **So really what I am asking is how do I circumvent a "Expect 100-continue" request from the client side so that I can upload/flash the firmware.**

I have tried numerous things such as using curl (which hangs). I also tried using Firefox portable (13_01) on Windows 7, but this results in a "No network access" message and I cannot subsequently connect to 192.168.0.1. The first thing I tried was modern Firefox on linux, but this does not work either (even changing it to HTML 1.0 does not work).

I am wondering if is an old linux browser that I can use (or how to resolve the "No network access" error on Windows. Or if there are simpler solutions to this problem.

Comment: Are you upgrading the firmware over Wi-Fi or using an Ethernet cable?

Comment: @Breakthrough Ethernet but that's not the problem because I can access the recovery console but I cannot upload the firmware because the browser expects a 100-continue which it never receives.

Comment: So uploading the firmware the normal way through the browser after a 30/30/30 reset does not work?

Comment: @Ramhound I'll refine the problem in the question.

Comment: Which revision of the DIR-615 do you have? Yours might support flashing over `tftp`, in case the Emergency Room web interface does not work.

Comment: @yjwong I have the HW revision E4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by disabling all DNS related services on the Windows 7 machine, and thereafter I could ping 192.168.0.1 and flash the firmware on there.