# Remove DD-WRT firmware on Linux (browser times out)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, firefox, dd-wrt

I want to restore my D-Link DIR-601 router to its factory firmware, following the instructions listed on the bottom of [this page](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DIR-601).

However, uploading the original firmware via the browser does **not** work. I am using Firefox 48.0 and Ubuntu 14.04. Firefox is stuck at "Sending request to 192.168.0.1" forever.

Is there a workaround?

I have tried:

1. The hard reset 30/30/30 rule
2. Older versions of Firefox (v3.0 and v30.0)
3. Chrome ([even though Firefox is the suggested browser](https://superuser.com/a/519803/454206))
4. tftp'ing the factory firmware right after resetting the router to its emergency state, i.e. when it's reachable at 192.168.0.1). The transfer times out even though the router is accessible via ping.

None of these helped.

Comment: There is also the tftp method.  May I ask why you want to restore the factory firmware?

Comment: Please see: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Recover_from_a_bad_flash

Comment: I had a similar issue but on Windows XP and my router was Dlink DIR 615. In my case I eventually tried with an older version of Firefox and then it worked.

Comment: @GregoryWolf Will look into tftp and report back, thanks. I want an OpenVPN client and I've only found it on an OpenWrt image. https://reddit.com/r/openwrt/comments/2snqq7/openvpn_on_dir601a_custom_build/ From what I read, it is not advised to switch from DD-WRT to OpenWrt directly, so I figured I'd use the factory firmware as a layover. Would you say that's the right approach?

Comment: You are trying to route all of your internet traffic through a VPN, yeah? You can use ipkg to install OpenWRT repositories (such as openvpn) https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Ipkg

I know it's frustrating when you install dd-wrt and you want additional packages. Using ipkg has worked for me.

Comment: @GregoryWolf: Thank you for the ipkg pointer. I looked into it and unfortunately it's a no go. There is apparently less than 324kB free in the DIR-601's 4MB flash memory (http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=639704), and (from what I can tell?) that "mini" firmware version that could work for JFFS (https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Jffs#Directions_for_.28normal.29_users:_using_Web-GUI_Interface) is not available for Atheros chipsets. Bummer. I'll look into tftp as this seems to be my only bet now. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @pat2015: I tried with version 30.0 (circa 2014) and 3.0 (circa 2008!) and they both failed to upload the file. NetHogs shows 0.3 to 0.4 kB sent from Firefox and that's it. (Note that pinging the router seems to work just fine during this process.)

Comment: Just an update that the tftp method failed as well. The transfer times out even though the router is accessible via ping. I've tried this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Some D-link routers have an emergency firmware upload page built in. Unplug, hold down the reset button, then plugin and wait 10 seconds. Release reset button. Now set your lan adapter to 192.168.0.10/255.255.255.0 then try http://192.168.0.1/ - This should then take you to the emergency firmware upload page. The emergency page may also be at 192.168.1.1 so update the above as appropriate.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing, see the first link in my question. As I wrote, the problem is that all browsers I've tried cannot seem to upload the firmware to the router.

Comment: I have had problems with that page on Ubuntu. Try connecting via windows, create a new user (temp) and login as that. Use internet explorer to go to the emergency page. If the page crashes or you don't see the 'Upload Successful' message then the firmware you have may be incorrect. Double check the revision of the hardware.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help people who have no access to a Windows system at all.  :-(

Comment: Virtualise a copy of XP using virtualbox. Use 512mb ram & 8gb HDD - Make sure the vm is on same network as router then use ie6 to upload. Brian, you have no excuses now.